# Problems with Insignia Bluetooth mouse continually losing connection, then restablishes. HID connection errors

Tags: networking, mouse, bluetooth, bluez

I have recently moved from 18.04 to 19.04 and started having problems with my Insignia Bluetooth mouse maintaining its connection. Looking at `/var/log/syslog`, it appears the root cause is the HID connection:

```
bluetoothd[1076]: connect error: Host is down (112)
```

To my knowledge, I am using the latest stable bluez package (`5.50`).

I've attempted a number of times to remove/pair/connect the mouse using `bluetoothctl` to no avail. I've repeatedly restarted the `bluetooth` service (even with `-d` enabled).

For what it's worth, I'm using a Broadcom wireless card:

```
[    1.366398] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[   29.159656] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4359 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[   31.421430] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
```

I have also installed the BCM file (which was missing):

```
[   29.757341] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[   29.758337] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[   31.405435] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1465
```

Here is a recent subset of `/var/log/syslog` filtered by the mouse device ID:

```
Feb 26 15:48:45 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 15:48:45 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 15:48:45 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 15:48:46 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 15:48:46 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 15:48:46 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 15:48:46 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 5
Feb 26 15:48:46 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 15:48:46 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 15:50:24 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 15:50:24 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 15:50:24 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 15:50:24 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 15:50:24 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 15:50:24 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 15:50:49 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x55bf4f4476b0: device 24:73:24:03:49:AD profile input-hid state changed: disconnected -> connecting (0)
Feb 26 15:50:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connect_failed_callback() hci0 24:73:24:03:49:AD status 4
Feb 26 15:50:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0x4
Feb 26 15:50:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x55bf4f4476b0: device 24:73:24:03:49:AD profile input-hid state changed: connecting -> disconnected (-5)
Feb 26 15:59:53 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 15:59:53 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 15:59:53 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 15:59:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 15:59:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 15:59:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 15:59:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 15:59:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 15:59:55 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 16:00:03 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 16:00:03 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 16:00:03 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
Feb 26 16:00:04 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 24:73:24:03:49:AD connected eir_len 31
Feb 26 16:00:05 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3
Feb 26 16:00:05 glenn-Aspire-V5-571 bluetoothd[947]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 24:73:24:03:49:AD type 0 status 0xe
```

The key is the number of times that it occurs over a 10 minute range and the consistent response of **`device 24:73:24:03:49:AD disconnected, reason 3`**.

**I also have a Bluetooth speaker connected and it has no problem remaining connected.**

Here is the output of `btmon` when trying to connect my mouse:

```
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13                                                                                                                                       #75 [hci0] 122.833911
        Address: 24:73:24:03:49:AD (OUI 24-73-24)
        Packet type: 0xcc18
          DM1 may be used
          DH1 may be used
          DM3 may be used
          DH3 may be used
          DM5 may be used
          DH5 may be used
        Page scan repetition mode: R2 (0x02)
        Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
        Clock offset: 0x0000
        Role switch: Allow slave (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                                                                                    #76 [hci0] 122.969527
      Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11                                                                                                                                                 #77 [hci0] 128.201078
        Status: Page Timeout (0x04)
        Handle: 12
        Address: 24:73:24:03:49:AD (OUI 24-73-24)
        Link type: ACL (0x01)
        Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Connect Failed (0x000d) plen 8                                                                                                                                            {0x0002} [hci0] 128.201147
        BR/EDR Address: 24:73:24:03:49:AD (OUI 24-73-24)
        Status: Connect Failed (0x04)
@ MGMT Event: Connect Failed (0x000d) plen 8                                                                                                                                            {0x0001} [hci0] 128.201147
        BR/EDR Address: 24:73:24:03:49:AD (OUI 24-73-24)
        Status: Connect Failed (0x04)
= bluetoothd: connect error: Host is down (112)
```

Comment: Does this problem occur with any other Bluetooth devices, e.g., a smartphone or keyboard?

Comment: I had the same problems with wireless bluetooth mouses and keyboards and not only in Ubuntu. I just switched to wired ones to save my nerves. Have you tried to use your bluetooth device in windows?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I don't have any other bluetooth devices that I use. I had to replace my failing wired mouse and opted for a bluetooth variant. I will test my same mouse on Windows and report back to this thread on how it behaves.

Comment: @Gryu: I connected to Windows and once paired, it remained connected for several hours.

Comment: For me, I'm most curious if the HID service is local and how the connection is established (and whether there is a more detailed log of that exchange).